# Need help undeleting questions

Tags: support, status-completed, undelete

Being new to SO, I asked some stupid/useless questions, which got downvoted. So I decided to to suppress them. Result: I'm banned and can no longer ask questions. So I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers), where it's stated:

> **Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!**

Problem: I can't edit a question that no longer exists. If anyone could be kind enough to undelete them, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I undeleted your latest question. It seems to have taken care of your question ban as well, although you're still on the verge of getting blocked again. I strongly suggest still going through and editing your earlier posts as well as taking care when posting questions in the future.

It looks like you discovered the answer to the question I restored and that's why you removed it. (If I read the comments right). The best thing to do in this situation is to post an answer of your own rather than remove the question. That way someone in the future can still benefit from your work.

Comment: Thank you very much. It did found the answer to the problem, and I will write a proper answer to it.